# How can I install MacOS security updates when I receive the error message "In order to continue installing, you need to be an owner"

Tags: macos, updates, ownership, software-update

Installing Apple MacOS security updates fails with the error message

> In order to continue installing, you need to be an owner

[image]

How can I fix this? Running MacOS 12.

Answer (score 2):

*Short: try enabling FileVault, and restarting.*

I previously could not install important security updates on my Mac with the error message that I would need to be an owner to install the updates.

I think I've now found the reason for this: there are two requirements for an user to install (some) updates:

1. they must be an owner of the computer's volume, and
2. have administrator privileges.

While my user account was in the admin group, I wasn't an owner of the volume.

I've found an [Apple support article](https://support.apple.com/en-om/guide/deployment/dep24dbdcf9e/web) outlining this and the respective solutions.

In my case, I found this way only after enabling FileVault on this machine. Enabling FileVault also creates the necessary pre-conditions for ownership, I think. There are currently no updates available that I can test this with.

On a related note, Apple Wallet and Apple Pay can also only be setup with either FileVault enabled or the solutions outlined in the article, probably because this creates the necessary security tokens for Apple to allow the storage of the payment details.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Felix question and answer, since I can't comment:

This problem can happen when you create a [mobile user account](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/create-and-configure-mobile-accounts-mh32157/mac) from a Network Account (e.g. active directory or LDAP).
During creation it will ask you about enabling File Vault.

I had (accidentally) skipped this step. I ended up with an Admin user that could do everything an administrator can do except for performing System Updates. It didn't display a helpful error message. It simply refused to accept the mobile user accounts password.

The only way to update was to switch to a user that had been created by the first user created on the device. Users created from my mobile user account (Administrator) could not perform updates as well.
Felix' answer and the referred Apple document explain this. The user didn't own the volume and thus couldn't inherit ownership as well. But ownership is required to perform updates.

I'm not sure if this can be reproduced and I don't want to try it out. My experience was on MacBook Pro 16" with M2 Pro (Apple Silicon) with macOS 13.4.